# How to get cumulative sum for all possible entries in columns even if they are null at the initial date, or not present at other dates in the dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, null, cumulative-sum

I have open source data for covid vaccinations which can be downloaded from GitHub https://github.com/ndoh-evds/evds-data-analytics/blob/main/Vaccination%20Data/2022-08-18/sacoronavirus_total_number_individuals_vaccinated_2022-08-18.csv. There is a sample code below for the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sacoronavirus_total_number_individuals_vaccinated_2022-07-06.csv')
```

[image: initial sample]

I have resampled from daily to monthly get the monthly sum for each `district` at an `age_group`,`sex` using the code below:

```
df['visit_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['visit_date'])
grouper = ['district',pd.Grouper(key='visit_date', freq='M'),'province','age_group','sex']
res1 = df.groupby(grouper)['total_number_individuals_vaccinated'].sum().reset_index()
```

All the possible entries for `age_group` are **18-34, 35-49, 50-59, 60+** whilst for `sex` are **Male,Female, Unidentified**. Because in COVID in RSA, not all age groups were vaccinated at the same time, and not all possible entries are present. So when calculating the cumulative sum of vaccinations using:

```
df_merged = res1.copy()
df_merged = df_merged.sort_values(['visit_date'])
df_merged['cumulative_vaccinations'] = df_merged.groupby(['district','age_group', 'sex'])['total_number_individuals_vaccinated'].cumsum(axis=0)
```

We get the correct answer in terms of `cumulative_vaccinations` but how can fill zero for null or not present entries for each `age_group` and `sex` for each resampled month (i.e. so there is 18-34, 35-39, 50-59, 60+ and Male, female, Unidentified for each `district` and `visit_date`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.fillna(0)` to replace null values with 0.